# How to style a programmatically created page with a template?

Tags: 7, forms, theming, routes

I'm struggling with understanding theming pages with templates. I'm stuck with creating a new template for a programmatically created page. I have a module that shows a download page for a file. The page is basically a form where user can click Submit and get their file downloaded. I construct the whole form programmatically in a page callback. But what if I want to style it with a template? I fail to see how to do it. Here is my (simplified) code:

```php
// Implements hook_menu()
function mymodule_menu()
{
    $items = array();    
    $items['file/%mymodule_mycustomfile/download'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_mymodule_filedownload',
    'title' => 'Page Title',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

// Implements autoloader %mymodule_mycustomfile
function mymodule_mycustomfile_load($fid)
{
    return ($fid > 0) ? (object)array('fid' => $fid) : FALSE;
}

// Page callback function
function _mymodule_filedownload($mycustomfile)
{
    return drupal_get_form('_mymodule_filedownload_form', $mycustomfile);
}

// Creates page form
function _mymodule_filedownload_form($form, &$form_state, $mycustomfile)
{
    $form['label'] = array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => 'File ID');
    $form['fid'] = array('#type' => 'item', '#markup' => $mycustomfile->fid);
    $form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Download');
    return $form;
}

// Submit button click handler
function _mymodule_filedownload_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{ 
    die('On Submit');
}
```

You can see that I construct my form fully in `_mymodule_filedownload_form()`. But I want to have something like file-download.tpl.php for it and put things like Label there. I fail to see how to do it. My problems are:

1) I stumbled upon `theme_hook_suggestions` and by default Drupal suggests the following template names: page__file, page__file__%, page__file__1, page__file__download. When I created page--file--download.tpl.php and went to /file/1/download, my screen went blank. I do not know how to output my form in this file and I'm afraid I do not even want to restyle the whole page. I only need to style the page content (the form itself) and leave the page alone. Why can't I have file--download.tpl.php if I have node.tpl.php and comment.tpl.php?

2) As a side note, when you execute `template_preprocess_page(&$variables)` on node pages, you can see the defined `$variables['node']` that contains full node object. How is it done? Can I possibly have something like `$variables['mycustomfile']` on my file download pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your page is a form, so you need to create a form template this way:

Implement hook_form_alter() in a module or template.php and set the form's #theme property:

```
function _mymodule_filedownload_form($form, &$form_state, $mycustomfile)
{
    ...
    $form['#theme'] = array('mymodule_filedownload_form');
    ...

}
```

Then implement new theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  return array(
    'mymodule_filedownload_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'form--mymodule_filedownload_form',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
    ),
  );
}
```

And then add form--mymodule_filedownload_form.php template with follow code to render complete form (you can render it also by components):

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
```

Comment: thanks. I managed to figure out most of your solution myself, but what I lacked was $form['#theme'] = array('mymodule_filedownload_form'); Now I can use a template.